# Extracting month from timestamp by specifying the date format of the timestamp in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a data set with a timestamp in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. I would like to extract the month and the year for the whole column. So I used the following code:

Extracting the year

```
`df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).year`
```

Extracting the month

```
`df['month_num'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).month`
```

Converting number of month in name of month

```
`df['Month'] = df['month_num'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])`
`df.drop(['month_num'], axis=1, inplace=True)`
```

However, the above returns the wrong month as sometimes it takes the month from the second pair of details (as if date format were in dd/mm/yyyy, which in fact it is), and sometimes it takes the month from the first pair of details (as if date format were in mm/dd/yyyy, which is not). So as you can see below, it returns 'Feb' for what should be 'Jan', although 'Dec' is correct.

```
`02/01/2020 12:07:00    EURUSD  EUR 138,476.70  2020    Feb`
`02/01/2020 12:02:12    GBPHKD  GBP 13,545.93   2020    Feb`
`31/12/2019 16:35:48    GBPUSD  USD 537.60      2019    Dec`
`31/12/2019 16:29:34    GBPHKD  HKD 279.17      2019    Dec`
```

I also tried to change the original timestamp format to yyyy-mm-dd but when changing the format it keep taking the month with a different order.

Any idea for this? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

use `strftime('%b')` and `assign`

ensure your datecolumn is a proper date `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

```
df.assign(year = df[0].dt.year,
          month = df[0].dt.strftime('%b'))
print(df)
           0         1       2    3           4  year month
0 2020-02-01  12:07:00  EURUSD  EUR  138,476.70  2020   Feb
1 2020-02-01  12:02:12  GBPHKD  GBP   13,545.93  2020   Feb
2 2019-12-31  16:35:48  GBPUSD  USD      537.60  2019   Dec
3 2019-12-31  16:29:34  GBPHKD  HKD      279.17  2019   Dec
```